# Can't align an A tag with below my image within an list

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align my text/anchor tag below my image but I'm unable to do this, I've tried doing `display:block;` but this didnt'work.

```css
/* Car showcase */
.car-showcase {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.car-showcase ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.car-showcase ul li {
    display: inline;
}

.car-showcase ul li a {
    color: white;
    background-color: #ae9595;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.1% 3%;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.car-showcase ul li a:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.719);
    border: solid 1px black;
}

.car-model {
    width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="car-showcase">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img class="car-model" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/09/13/03/bike-riding-5557589_1280.png">
            <a href="#">View car</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="car-model" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/09/13/03/bike-riding-5557589_1280.png">
            <a href="#">View car</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="car-model" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/09/13/03/bike-riding-5557589_1280.png">
            <a href="#">View car</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm trying to achieve them all being inline with the View Car button below the image/carmodel.
Any answers to guide me in the right direction and teach me would be extremely appreciated as I'm learning HTML in Gymnasium right now.

Answer (score 1):

See: https://codepen.io/koder613/pen/MWydYOM?editors=1100

I changed:

```
.car-showcase ul li {
    display: inline-block; // was inline
}
```

I wrapped the `a` tag in a `<figcaption>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
.car-showcase ul li {
    display:grid;
}
```

Comment: Have you test it before write answer?

Comment: @ShivangSharma Try to explain what the code does in your answer.

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27273099).

Answer (score 0):

If you float the list to the left and add display:block to link it will work. This will also add a bit of space between each one and the link will be the width of the image.

```
    .car-showcase ul li {
        float:left; 
        margin-right:10px;
    }
    
    .car-showcase ul li a {
        color: white;
        background-color: #ae9595;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 0.1% 3%;
        transition: 0.5s;
        display:block;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

like that?

```css
/* Car showcase */
.car-showcase {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.car-showcase ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.car-showcase ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.car-showcase ul li a {
    color: white;
    background-color: #ae9595;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.1% 3%;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.car-showcase ul li a:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.719);
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="car-showcase">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <img class="car-model" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"><br>
                <a href="#">View car</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img class="car-model" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"><br>
                <a href="#">View car</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img class="car-model" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"><br>
                <a href="#">View car</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

i change `inline` with `inline-block` in `.car-showcase ul li`  then add `<br>`

Comment: This worked however I had to get rid of the width being set to a % and replace it with being set to a set pixel instead. Does this affect responsiveness?

Comment: yes i deleted to but you can change the width of container. just try and test :)

Answer (score -1):

anchors are a bit tricky when aligning them properly, try puting a paragraph tag whithin the anchor and style the paragraph anchor with a width of 100%

Comment: <a href="#"><p style="width:100%;float:left;">View car</p></a>